# Open and close forms onclick javascript

Tags: javascript, forms

I made form open on button click with simple script

```
<script>
function showMsg(){
document.message.style.visibility="visible";
}
</script>
```

Form appears, everything works. Now i've added an x to make this form hidden again, i've tried various script but nothing worked. Maybe i need to set div hidden instead of form? Any sugestions?
Here's my code

```
<div id="msg"><class="button" onclick="showMsg();">
<form style="visibility:hidden" name="message" method="post" action="contact.php">
<br><br>
<div id="demo">
<table width="230px" align="center" style="box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 0px rgba(0, 0, 
0, 100);">
<tr><td colspan=1></td></tr>
<tr>
<td><a href="#" class="close-classic"></a></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is that actually your HTML or have you typed it in here and made a few mistakes?

Comment: you should use the `display` attribute instead of the `visibility` attribute

Comment: It's how it this, i just shorten the table here.

Comment: you have `><` in your `a` tag (before class) that doesnt belong and you do not close your first `a` tag, fix and try again.

Comment: Yeah i know i fixed that earlier (and tried now again) but somehow then my form doesn't appear.

Comment: With broken html, nothing will work :(

Comment: Well i edited my code, now it's without unnecessary `a` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a very simple, barebones code of what you're trying to do:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LJIre

You should first clean and fix your code as other users have suggested and build from there.